# How to Overly Text and Button on an Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place Text and button on an image like this. Can someone help with this. [image]

this is what I have tried. The thing is it does render properly in outlook email

CSS:

```
 .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
    }
    
    .container img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .container .btn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background-color: #55A646;
      color: white;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 24px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container .btn:hover {
      background-color: #55A646 ;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://image.com" alt="" style="width:100%">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried, what is your HTML structure and CSS so far ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: updated with the question with code.

Answer (score 0):

Folow The link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

```css
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

/* Bottom center text */
.bottom-center {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 45%;
}



/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.searchenginejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/the-essential-guide-to-using-images-legally-online-760x400.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-center">
    <button>Bottom Center</button>
  </div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #55A646;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .btn:hover {
  background-color: #00cc00 ;
}
h4{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  background:#111;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf3jO.png" alt="" style="width:100%">
  <h4>The table Fan</h4>
  <button class="btn">Fan</button>
</div>
```